# MySQL: Many Indexes, but on small fields

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a `BOOK` table consits of 15 columns, but most of them are small integers(`INT(1)` for different ratings, and also somewhere `INT(4)` or `INT(5)`)

The table is meant to be used for dynamic search with filters on web-site. In order to speed things up, I created indexes on almost every `INT` column (10-11 indexes in total). I don't have most of data in table yet, but will I have any memory trouble in prospect of huge table?

My question in general - does small integer index require comparatively more memory than I expect?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between 11 indexes on 1 field each and 1 index over 11 fields. However, although you specify your integer as int(1), it still consumes 4 bytes, only the possible values are restricted. You may consider using tinyint(1)

Comment: Indexes are created based on queries and not blindly on every column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier to shrink the datatypes before you have a zillion rows in the table.

`INT UNSIGNED` takes 4 bytes and allows numbers from 0 to about 4 billion.
`TINYINT UNSIGNED` takes 1 byte and allows values 0..255.  So, if you have a billion-row table, changing an `INT` to `TINYINT` would shrink the disk footprint by 3GB, plus another 3GB if it is also in an index.  (This is a simplification; hope you get the idea.)

`SMALLINT UNSIGNED` takes 2 bytes, allowing 0..65535.  That is probably what you want instead of `INT(4)` and maybe `INT(5)`?

The `(5)` means *nothing* (except when used with `ZEROFILL`).

Your table will probably be 1/3 data and 2/3 index.  This ratio is abnormal, but not "bad".

Instead of 10-11 single-column indexes, I recommend you make about that many 2-column indexes.  This will improve some more queries.

You need to get a feel for the traffic -- what columns do people *usually* filter on?  And how do they filter?  That is `a=7` versus `a>7`.

Once you have some likely `SELECTs`, study my [*Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) to see how to optimize the indexes.  After that, come back with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECTs`; I may suggest further tweaks.

I would not hesitate to build a table like yours with a billion rows, even if I did not have enough RAM to cache it all.